# Google Colab source function in other Colab notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have an ipynb on Google Colab `my_functions.ipynb` which consists of a simple function.

```
def get_mean(dat, col_nm):
  return dat[col_nm].mean()
```

From a different python notebook `other_notebook.ipynb` on Google Colab I'd like to source this function so that I could use it however I haven't been able to see a solution anywhere.

Appreciate any help on this.

Thanks,

Gareth

Comment: This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47345004/in-googles-colab-notebook-how-do-i-call-a-function-from-a-python-file/47356505

Answer (score 3):

I saved my file with some useful functions as a .py file.

Then I store in Google Drive as 'functions.py'.

I then load my functions with the following call:

```
%run '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/functions.py'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

then

```
libdir = "/content/gdrive/My\ Drive/Colab\ Notebooks/lib/"
%run {libdir}my_functions.ipynb
```

Now, all you've defined in `my_functions.ipynb` becomes available in the scope of your current notebook.
Same thing you can do with regular `.py` files as well.